# VSTS Can we use App service as a machine with Deploy Visual Studio Test Agent Task

Tags: selenium, continuous-integration, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a selenium code which has written with C#. I wanted to do CI with VSTS.
With the build configuration I have to set Machine with "Deploy Visual Studio Test Agent Task". Can we use "App Service: for that?
If so what do we need to take as Admin username and password?

Comment: Do you solve it with a VM in azure?

Comment: Nope. s VMs are expensive I used headless browser, so I can use Vs Test task.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dgartner/2016/02/23/running-selenium-tests-as-part-of-your-release-with-vsts-release-management/

Comment: Yes, you can use VS Test task to run test too. You can accept my reply as answer if it helps you to solve the original issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can’t, you need to specify the machine(s) (e.g. the VM in azure).

Comment: I'm new to azuar so pardon me . Can a Azuar app service be a machine?

Comment: @Thinkx Azure runs apps on fully managed virtual machines (VMs), but you can't access/connect to these vms, more information: [What is Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-value-prop-what-is). To deploy VS Test Agent, you can create a Virtual machine in azure:[Virtual Machines Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/)